# How to check if a float value is increasing or decreasing

Tags: c#, c++, windows, floating-point, integer

I have calculated distance between user left and right hand in a float value. 
If hands come closer => distance gets approx 0.00xxxx
If hands move apart => distance get bigger approx 2.0000

Since these values are in float and they continuously change so IF conditions are not sufficient.

How  do I check programmatically if a value lets say x is increasing from 
      X=0.0 to X=0.5
or decreasing from
      x=0.5 to x=0

So that do action X if it increases or Do action Z if it decreases.
    . I have used the following logic to zoom out but it's not very smooth.

```
  if (distance < 1 && distance > 0.65 && leftHandFront && rightHandFront)

                        {
                                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, -120, 0);

                            }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. `if` works fine with floats as long as you are testing for greater or less than.

Comment: I have tested using IF, but the distance values overlaps between increasing(hands moving apart)  and decreasing(hands coming close). So the zoom in works fine but it does not work well simultaneously  with zoom out gesture.

Comment: I think you need to keep a record of the previous distance and compare that with the current distance.

Comment: @Galik Can you please show a code based example on how can I track the  distance variable previous value? I mean the current values are continuously changing and those if checks are on those current values as user is moving hands but what exactly is meant by previous distance?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but this might be what you are looking for (its not a working example).

```
float prev_distance = 0.0;

while(true) // keep looping
{
    float distance = calculate_distane(); // get distance

    if(distance < prev_distance)
    {
        // do X
    }
    else
    {
        // do Z
    }

    prev_distance = distance; // remember this dustance for next time
}
```